# When I move spam to my inbox, it goes back into the spam again using imap Program for yahoo?

Tags: php, imap

```
<?php

$mbox = imap_open("{imap.mail.yahoo.com:993/imap/ssl}Bulk Mail",$mailuser,$mailpass) 
      or die("can't connect: ".imap_last_error()); 
.
imap_mail_move($mbox,$messageset,"INBOX"); 
@imap_expunge($mbox);
imap_close($mbox);

?>
```

Its moving Successfully...

Comment: Did you turn off any spam protection on your account?

Comment: Have you tried moving stuff between other folders? Is it an issue specific to the spam folder? If so it's Yahoo's fault.

Comment: Spam mail moved to inbox successfully. Another new mail received for spam folder for yahoo. Not spam option not working for imap? Is it possible?